# Asp.Net Core Entity Framework Error "Exception Was Thrown While Attempting to Evaluate a LINQ Query Parameter Expression"

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am trying to search a row in a database using Entity Framework. I use 4 criteria for searching (searchOne, searchTwo, searchThree and searchFour) as shown below:

```
public async Task<List<ClassName>> Search(string searchOne, string searchTwo, string searchThree, string searchFour)
{
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchOne) || !String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchTwo) || !String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchThree) || !String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchFour))
    {
        return await _context.Class.Include(x => x.ClassContainForeignKey)
            .OrderBy(x => x.ID)
            .Where(x => x.SearchOne.ToLower().Contains(String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchOne.ToLower()) ? "" : searchOne.ToLower())
            && x.SearchTwo.ToLower().Contains(String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchTwo.ToLower()) ? "" : searchTwo.ToLower())
            && x.SearchThree.ToLower().Contains(String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchThree.ToLower()) ? "" : searchThree.ToLower())
            && x.SearchFour.ToLower().Contains(String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchFour.ToLower()) ? "": searchFour.ToLower())).ToListAsync();
    }
    else
    {
        return await _context.Class.Include(x => x.ClassContainForeignKey).OrderBy(x => x.ID).ToListAsync();
    }
}
```

Unfortunately the code is not working. I debugged the code, and I found that error come from the returning data area:

```
return await _context.Class.Include(x => x.ClassContainForeignKey)
            .OrderBy(x => x.ID)
            .Where(x => x.SearchOne.ToLower().Contains(String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchOne.ToLower()) ? "" : searchOne.ToLower())
            && x.SearchTwo.ToLower().Contains(String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchTwo.ToLower()) ? "" : searchTwo.ToLower())
            && x.SearchThree.ToLower().Contains(String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchThree.ToLower()) ? "" : searchThree.ToLower())
            && x.SearchFour.ToLower().Contains(String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchFour.ToLower()) ? "": searchFour.ToLower())).ToListAsync();
```

I see this error:

> One or more errors occurred (An exception was thrown while attempting to evaluate a LINQ query parameter expression. See the inner exception for more information. To show additional information call 'DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging'.)

What did I try: I searched many questions to solve this issue, but I didn't solve it until now:

1. [InvalidOperationException: An exception was thrown while attempting to evaluate a LINQ query parameter expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62806208/invalidoperationexception-an-exception-was-thrown-while-attempting-to-evaluate)
2. [An exception was thrown while attempting to evaluate a LINQ query parameter expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65813688/an-exception-was-thrown-while-attempting-to-evaluate-a-linq-query-parameter-expr)
3. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/704a5c1c-2ce2-4df3-815f-d9eae33dc31d/how-to-search-multiple-criteria-in-entity-framework-mvc?forum=aspmvc

What I am expecting:

1. How can I solve this problem using Entity Framework Core not LINQ?
2. How to search more than one value criteria using Entity Framework Core with only one if statement?

Comment: Tested without "Include(x => x.ClassContainForeignKey)" all works. If you still havent' solve the issue you can post more codes about the class defination.

Comment: Thank you @Jerry, but I need to include the foreign key class `ClassContainForeignKey` because I need to bring its data to use it for getting some details.

also I tested it without `Include(x => x.ClassContainForeignKey)`, but its not working.

Comment: That is strange. I just create a class with Searchone, Searchtow , Searchthree, Searchfour element and filtered successfully. would you mind show a picture of your class table top line.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the `String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace` can not be translated to an SQL statement - replace `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace` with a `null` check and a check to an empty string and it should work.

Comment: I tried to change `String.IsNullOrEmpty` with `String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace`, but still showing same error.